# javascript: match two javascript objects implicitly and create a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am new to javascript and json objects. I am processing an array in which each element looks like below :

```
 input = { 
      clgid: 135,
      careerlevelid: 10000130,
      metricname: 'joiners',
      monthnames: '201810,201811,201812,20184,20185,....',
      metricvalue: '18.00,0.00,7.00,15.00,0.00,0.00,....' 
      }
```

`monthanames` - can be any from 1 to 24

`metricvalue` -  is the corresponding value for that monthname

I want an out put like below :

```
output = { 
  clgid: 135,
  careerlevelid: 10000130,
  metricname: 'joiners',
   201810: 18.00,
  201811: 0.00,
  201812: 7.00,
  201804: 15.00,
  201805: 0.00,

}
```

Iam trying to do this using a for loop() and a TSMap (https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-map) but somehow i am not able to get the desired output.

Comment: The output is not valid JS. Is `metricname` supposed to be a long string with commas in it?

Comment: Your desired output for `metircname` is invalid syntax. It would need to be `metricname: ['joiners', {201810:18.00}, {201811:0, etc.}]` because data structures can't be expresses as the comma separated list you are showing. Also, there is no such thing as "json objects". JSON is a string format.

Comment: Is there a certain requirement to have an object like that (actually the keys will be strings). Why do not to try to have an approach like monthnames[0] matches metricvalue[0] (split by comma)

Comment: @stefanz While the keys can be accessed as strings, there is no need to actually quote them when declaring an object literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [destructuring with rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to get the `monthnames`, `metricvalue`, and `base` (the other properties).

[`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `monthnames`, and `metricvalue` to arrays.

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the `months`. Get the respective value from the `values`, and create an object.

Combine with `base` using [`Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

**Note 1:** The months would be ordered by the numeric value of their key.

**Note 2:** Converting the values to numbers removes the redundant decimal points.

```js
const input = {
  clgid: 135,
  careerlevelid: 10000130,
  metricname: 'joiners',
  monthnames: '201810,201811,201812,20184,20185',
  metricvalue: '18.00,0.00,7.00,15.00,0.00,0.00'
};

const reformatMonthes = (obj) => {
  const { monthnames, metricvalue, ...base } = input;
  const months = monthnames.split(',');
  const values = metricvalue.split(',');
  
  return Object.assign(
    base,
    ...months.map((m, i) => ({
      [m]: +values[i]
    }))
  );
};
console.log(reformatMonthes(input));
```

To preserve the order, it's better to use an array of month objects:

```js
const input = {
  clgid: 135,
  careerlevelid: 10000130,
  metricname: 'joiners',
  monthnames: '201810,201811,201812,20184,20185',
  metricvalue: '18.00,0.00,7.00,15.00,0.00,0.00'
};

const reformatMonthes = (obj) => {
  const { monthnames, metricvalue, ...base } = input;
  const months = monthnames.split(',');
  const values = metricvalue.split(',');
  
  return {
    ...base,
    months: months.map((m, i) => ({
      [m]: +values[i]
    }))
  };
};
console.log(reformatMonthes(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Map to create a new property.

```js
let input = { 
      clgid: 135,
      careerlevelid: 10000130,
      metricname: 'joiners',
      monthnames: '201810,201811,201812,20184,20185',
      metricvalue: '18.00,0.00,7.00,15.00,0.00,0.00' 
      };
      
let months = input.monthnames.split(',');
let values = input.metricvalue.split(',');
input.metricname = [input.metricname, ...months.map((month, i) => month+':'+values[i])];



console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
 "clgid": 135,
 "careerlevelid": 10000130,
 "metricname": "joiners",
 "monthnames": "201810,201811,201812,20184,20185",
 "metricvalue": "18.00,0.00,7.00,15.00,0.00"
};

// Split month names string to convert it into an array.
var monthnames = jsonObj.monthnames.split(',');

// Split metric value string to convert it into an array.
var metricvalue = jsonObj.metricvalue.split(',');

// delete monthnames property from an jsonObj.
delete jsonObj.monthnames;

// delete metricvalue property from an jsonObj.
delete jsonObj.metricvalue;

// iterate monthnames to assign the array elements as key in jsonObj.
for (var i in monthnames) {
    jsonObj[monthnames[i]] = metricvalue[i];
}

// Output
console.log(jsonObj);
```